# convert some value from mysql query using php

Tags: php, mysql

using `php` I make a `query` to `mysql`. Inside my `query`, some values are in seconds (just some of them), I'd like to convert them into `mm:ss.` So I need to move into my "array" query and I do not understand how to move inside my query result, attribute after attribute.

Here is my db :

[image]

In my `php` code, I make the query and then for each row I put it inside an array.

```
$data=array(); 
$q=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM TEST3612 WHERE user_id=$queryid"); 

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)) {
    //$data[]=gmdate("H:i:s", $row%86400); 
    $data[]=$row;
}
```

I'd like then to move into my array, and when I have the attribute CS for example, convert the value.

Here is what I tried :

```
foreach($data as $value) {
    if ($value['CS']) {
        $value['CS'] = gmdate("H:i:s", $value%86400); 
    }
}
```

I got an error. I don't know how to move into my `array`, a select a element of a `object`. I thought I did it good but apparently no.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: What error did you get? Can you please add the error output to the question above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`mysqli_fetch_object`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) returns objects, not arrays. Also you used `$value` instead of `$value->CS` inside of `gmdate`. So you should iterate like this:

```
foreach($data as $value) {
    if ($value->CS) {
        $value->CS = gmdate("H:i:s", $value->CS % 86400); 
    }
}
```

Alternativly you can write this directly in your while loop, so you don't need the foreach loop. I would say this is the better solutions because you don't write unnecessary code and performance gets improved a little bit:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($q)) {
    if ($row->CS) {
        $row->CS = gmdate("H:i:s", $row->CS % 86400); 
    }

    $data[] = $row;
}
```